# KeyError: "None of [Index(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, keyerror

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
weekday     mean sum
Friday      160 26572
Monday      150 73762
Saturday    55  67256
Sunday      626 22222
Thursday    133 34566
```

`weekday` is the index and `mean` and `sum` are the columns.

What I now tried to do was to plot the dataframe and order the bars properly using this code:

```
df2['sum'].value_counts()[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']].plot(kind="bar")
```

But I got this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday',\n       'Sunday'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either `.loc` or `.reindex` to reorder the series:

```
(df2['sum']
  .loc[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']]
  .plot(kind="bar")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get the same error...

Comment: I think you don't need `value_counts()`, since that's gonna be indexed by the values in `sum` column. See updated answer.